# How to extract a number from a hyperlink with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the number `808` from this hyperlink:

```
<a class="a-link-normal feedback-detail-description" href="#"><b>100% positive</b> in the last 12 months (808 ratings)</a>
```

I have written the code below and it returns `[]`. I am not sure what I have to add to extract the number `808` as easy as possible.

Will highly appreciate some input!

```
seller_feedback_span = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "a-link-normal feedback-detail-description"})
print(seller_feedback_span)
```

Comment: it's within `<a>` tag, not `<div>`. try: `seller_feedback_span = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "a-link-normal feedback-detail-description"})`

Comment: @chitown88 it still returns `[]`

Comment: Given the html provided in your OP, it will not return an empty list. This leads me to believe you are pulling the html source from a dynamic page. So if you look at the page source, you'll see that, but if you look at what you're actually pulling, it's not within the html source code. what's the full code that you are using to pull this html?

Comment: @chitown88 This is the web page: `https://www.amazon.com/sp?_encoding=UTF8&asin=&isAmazonFulfilled=1&isCBA=&marketplaceID=ATVPDKIKX0DER&orderID=&seller=A4F1OVQERIAWX&tab=&vasStoreID=`

EDIT: Ok, I figured it out! It works now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: @chitown88 I used a link which referred to another web page and therefore, I was getting an empty list every time I ran the code. Once I changed the URL in the code to be the of the final web page, then, of course, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS selector which fast in retrieving data:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data='''<a class="a-link-normal feedback-detail-description" href="#"><b>100% positive</b> in the last 12 months (808 ratings)</a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')
item=soup.select_one('.feedback-detail-description').text.split('(')[1].split('ratings')[0].strip()

print(item)
```

Output:

```
808
```

Answer (score 1):

```
html = '''<a class="a-link-normal feedback-detail-description" href="#"><b>100% positive</b> in the last 12 months (808 ratings)</a>'''


from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

seller_feedback_span = soup.findAll("a", {"class": "a-link-normal feedback-detail-description"})
#print(seller_feedback_span)

for feedback in seller_feedback_span:
    rating = feedback.text.split('(')[-1].split('ratings')[0].strip()
    print (rating)
```

**Output:**

```
print (rating)
808
```

Answer (score 0):

With `soup.select` feature and specific regex pattern:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html_data = '''<a class="a-link-normal feedback-detail-description" href="#">
<b>100% positive</b> in the last 12 months (808 ratings)</a>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_data, 'html.parser')
seller_feedback_span = soup.select("a.a-link-normal.feedback-detail-description b")
rating = re.search(r'\d+(?=\s*ratings)', seller_feedback_span[0].nextSibling).group()

print(rating)   # 808
```